# Using function arguments directly vs Creating local variables

Tags: c++, optimization, execution-time

Consider these two implementations of a function:

```
double MyFoo::foo(std::vector<double> & v){
    double f1 = v.at(1);
    double f2 = v.at(2);
    double f3 = v.at(3);
    double f4 = v.at(4);
    double f5 = v.at(5);
    double f6 = v.at(6);    

    double ret = sin(f1)+ sin(f2)+ sin(f3)+ sin(f4)+ sin(f5)+ sin(f6)+ sin(f7);
    return ret;
}
```

and

```
double MyFoo::foo(std::vector<double> & v){
    double ret = sin(v.at(1))+ sin(v.at(2))+ sin(v.at(3))+ sin(v.at(4))+ sin(v.at(5))+ sin(v.at(6))+ sin(v.at(7));
    return ret;
}
```

Is there any noticeable difference (if any) in *execution time* of these functions? Do these local variable assignments introduce computational overhead or the compilers handles the useless local variables?

P.S. Choice of `sin()` is completely arbitrary. My question is focused on the local variables and not the operations happening inside.

Comment: A good compiler/optimizer would result in identical assembly for either scenario.  I believe the rational behind the optimization would be that the lvalue of the local variable doesn't change. As @Mats Persson stated, this is a marginal optimization at best, for values as simple as doubles, but could be significant for more memory intensive data types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without actually building a system that does this, I would GUESS that there's no difference at all. And `sin` tends to take quite some time anyway, so it's likely that any minor optimisation made on the use of local variables, etc is very marginal.

I'd expect that most "good" compilers (gcc, Microsoft, etc) would optimise out any local variable that isn't extensively used, and produce exactly the same code.

But like I said, without actually trying both methods, it's hard so say for sure [And I'd remove the call to `sin` too, since that's likely to "hide" any minor differences between the two variants - just adding the 6 double values would be a better solution].

If performance (in this function in particular) is of essence then produce a benchmark. But also, before you start "messing" with functions, make sure you know what functions consume most of the time in your code. It's not much point in shaving two clockcycles off a function that runs a few dozen times, when the whole execution time is several hours (so many billions of cycles).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Choice of `sin()` is completely arbitrary and my curiosity is on something else. It was just the first thing came to my mind. You can simply consider any other function!

Comment: Yes, my point is rather that if it takes one or two clockcycles to "fetch the `f1 = v.at(1)`", and then takes 200 clockcycles to calculate `sin(f1)`, it may be difficult to tell the difference between that and the `sin(v.at(1))`. Just adding the numbers together should be one or a few clock-cycles, so should show some difference - if there is a difference.